# How to disable HTML error responses when using Action(parse.json)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

In a REST API implemented with Play Framework (2.4), I'm using [`Action(parse.json)`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonHttp#Creating-a-new-entity-instance-in-JSON) to parse JSON from incoming POST request body.

With my current code (see below),

- Posting valid JSON with missing fields (e.g. `{"foo": ""}`) produces
  400 with the response body `{"error":"Missing input fields"}`. This is fine and expected.
- Posting completely invalid JSON (such as `{,,,}` or `{\00}`) produces
  400 with a [long HTML response body](https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/03c0973be9d40318d81a0bf2d69b3e09).  This comes from somewhere within
  `parse.json`.

In the latter case, **how to get rid of the HTML response body?** I'd like the response body to either contain a short JSON error message (such as `{"error":"Invalid JSON input"}`), or nothing at all. Does Play have a config option for this, or would I need to create a custom Action? What is the simplest way?

Controller method:

```
def test = Action(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[Input].map(i => {
    Ok(i.foo)
  }).getOrElse(BadRequest(errorJson("Missing input fields")))
}
```

Other stuff used above:

```
case class Input(foo: String, bar: String)

object Input {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Input]
}

case class ErrorJson(error: String)

object ErrorJson {
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[ErrorJson]
}

private def errorJson(message: String) = Json.toJson(ErrorJson(message))
```

Comment: Have you tried to override `onError` interceptor method on Global and catch the exception thrown to customize the error message?

Comment: There is no Global in my app; it's [deprecated](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings) in recent Play versions. Instead, providing [custom HttpErrorHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39794930/56285) is the way to go.

Comment: Ah I see. I use play 2.4

Comment: Yes, me too. In 2.4 (and 2.5 afaik) it is still possible to use many old APIs, which nonetheless are deprecated / no longer recommended; see [Play 2.4 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24).

Comment: official example: https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-rest-api-example/blob/2.6.x/app/ErrorHandler.scala
Im feeling that Play  is not Rest API friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The long html is produced by the default `HttpErrorHandler`. You can provide your own by following [this guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaErrorHandling#Supplying-a-custom-error-handler). Quoting the example code:

> ```
> class ErrorHandler extends HttpErrorHandler {
>
>   def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) = {
>     Future.successful(
>       Status(statusCode)("A client error occurred: " + message)
>     )
>   }
>
>   def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable) = {
>     Future.successful(
>       InternalServerError("A server error occurred: " + exception.getMessage)
>     )
>   }
> }
> ```

Note: if you manage your dependencies without Guice, you will have to provide your custom `HttpErrorHandler` in the `ApplicationLoader`

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty to add the code example right here. I use Guice (the default approach in Play 2.4+) so no problem there.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: in https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/48a76b851946261a952a2edcc4b8dbeeb303e07b/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/ContentTypes.scala#L379
there is

```
Json.parse(bytes.iterator.asInputStream)
```

`Json.parse` delegates to Jacksons' `parseJsValue`, which throws exception. I cannot follow the code properly, why the exception isn't caught properly inside `Iteratee` framework.

Most straightforward solution, would be to replicate the code in `ContentTypes.scala` catching the exception around `Json.parse` and properly turning it into `Left` value of `BodyParser`'s `Iteratee`. Unfortunately Play doesn't expose building blocks, so lot of copy-paste is needed if you want to do it as in Play.

Alternatively you could do dumb `Iteratee.fold` and direct `Json.parse` on accumulated bytearray, that's not good; you probably want to check accept headers , use bytearray builder, and limit the max size of the input

```
val betterJson: BodyParser[JsValue] = BodyParser("better json") { _request =>
  import play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution.Implicits.defaultExecutionContext

  Iteratee.fold(new Array[Byte](0)) { (bytes: Array[Byte], acc: Array[Byte]) =>
    bytes ++ acc
  } map { bytes =>
    val res: Either[Result, JsValue] = Try(Json.parse(bytes)) match {
      case Success(v) => Right(v)
      case Failure(e) => Left(BadRequest("bad json"))
    }
    res
  }
}
```

Using `betterJson` in a controller:

```
def test = Action(betterJson) { request =>
  request.body.validate[Int].map(i => {
    Ok(i.toString)
  }).getOrElse(BadRequest("my error"))
}
```

Tested with:

```
// works:
// $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '123' localhost:9000/test
// 123
// $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{}' localhost:9000/test
// my error
//
// issue:
// $ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '.' localhost:9000/test
// bad json
```